# SSL/HTTPS within an Amazon ELB workflow

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

So I've got a few EC2 instances acting as nodes on an ELB, and want to setup a wildcard certificate. Anyone have any good directions/links I can look into? I'm a little confused about the CSR file generation.

Comment: No need to post a greeting or sign your posts. Just post the question itself. We all know who you are, and your acceptance of our answers is thanks enough. :)

Comment: Just checking: Why do you need a wildcard as opposed to a standard cert? (If you've got an ELB fronting a single service, then you might only need the latter, and they're much cheaper)

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: Had this as comment before:

You will likely want to have the ELB pass the encrypted traffic to your EC2 instances where they can decrypt the traffic.  GoDaddy has a good set of link's on how to set this up for various systems.  Note, you do not have to use them for the SSL cert, but obviously the tutorial is centered on their service.

http://help.godaddy.com/topic/236/article/5537?locale=en

If you want a more technical explanation of what each file is, here are some links:

Wikipedia (technical): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Practical Example (Linux + Apache): http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the CSR with any web server you like and the process it through GoDaddy for your wildcard. Once you have it, export a PFX and use OpenSSL to extract the parts of the cert required for EC2 ELB.

http://sycure.wordpress.com/2008/05/15/tips-using-openssl-to-extract-private-key-pem-file-from-pfx-personal-information-exchange/

You will need the private, public certs.

Wildcard certs are no problem, I use several myself. They're obviously helpful if you plan on securing more than one URL under the same domain name.

Keep in mind, once you build the ELB instance, you can't change anything outside of the health checks.

Here is their doc on the matter too:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/index.html?InstallCert.html

Comment: "Once you build the ELB instance, you can't change anything outside of the health checks" - this isn't strictly true: if you're only using the GUI then yes, but you can change the SSL certificates and adjust setting using the command line API. Although this obviously requires quite a bit more technical know-how than the command line alone.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did - For those who want to know the exact steps..

1) Generate your key. Nothing special here just make sure that your `Common Name` matches

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout pivotal_combined_private.key -out pivotal_combined.csr
```

2) Get yourself a [multi-domain cert](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3908/defining-a-multiple-domain-ucc-ssl-certificate)
3) Convert the private key to an RSA Format

```
openssl rsa -in pivotal_combined_private.key -out pivotal_combined_private.rsa
```

4) Wait for the cert to come back...

5) Download and convert the certs to PEM format

```
openssl x509 -in pivotalenergysolutions.com.crt -out  input.der -outform DER
openssl x509 -in input.der -inform DER -out pivotalenergysolutions.com.pem -outform PEM
openssl x509 -in gd_bundle.crt -out  input.der -outform DER
openssl x509 -in input.der -inform DER -out gd_bundle.pem -outform PEM
```

6) Upload the whole thing..

```
iam-servercertupload -b pivotalenergysolutions.com.pem -c gd_bundle.pem -k pivotal_combined_private.rsa -s pivotalenergysolutions_combined
```

Hope that helps